# Is GoogleIdToken.Payload getSubject() the best db key for users when using Google authentication?

Tags: google-play-services, google-api-java-client

We are testing Google APIs Client Library (Java 1.17.0-rc) for OAuth authentication of our [Android app <> GAE server communication](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html). So we authorize an Account from Android only for our own web server audience (we don't use this for other Google services).

Overall it works well, very clean UI flow :)

However we need to create a server account for each Google authorized user, and I'm not sure what is the best database key for these users. We would use a field from the verified [GoogleIdToken.Payload](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.17.0-rc/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleIdToken.Payload.html), I see two choices:

**getSubject()** is the JWT principal (the user). From comments in the docs it sounds like this is an obfuscated Google user ID. If so this sounds like the best key for a user we create with Google's authentication, but I haven't found official docs to confirm this. Some questions:

- is it guaranteed unique between Google accounts?
- is it immutable for a google account?
- how to ask this politely :) Is this an "official" Google key for users that is likely to exist in the future, or something just part of this library's beta? We do not want to orphan all our server accounts!

**getEmail()** is also a possibility but:

- is it always present? In our test it is always set but the docs say "Returns the e-mail address of the user or null if it was not requested"
- is it immutable and unique for a google account? E.g. can a user account change their email?

btw just a note to others using these APIs, we found in our test that you cannot assume Account.name matches Payload.getEmail(), e.g. some German gmail users have different domains, case can differ etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a tentative answer from experimenting. I added a test to our app and it's now created a couple thousand user accounts on our server. It looks like GoogleIdToken Payload getSubject() is the same user ID as used for Google+ because A) it's the same format, and B) for users who are also logged in to g+ it is the same ID.

So I believe that getSubject(), or getId() as it was called in the earlier releases, is a Google universal user ID which is used for g+ accounts, but also just for anyone who has set up a Google account even if they have not explicitly gone through the g+ setup flow.

Can anyone confirm that?

So far the only time this user account creation flow does not work is most devices in China for which AccountManager getAccountsByType(GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE) returns zero Accounts.

Comment: Your answer is almost 4 years old now. Did you meet some problems with your approach to identify a user by `Payload.getSubject()` in the last years? For example: Did the ID of some users change, were some IDs of any users missing, did multiple users have the same ID, and so on...?